# My teen wets the bed. He is in diapers just at night but he says it’s hard to sleep because "the diaper feels weird”

Tags: sleep, teen, diaper, bed-wetting, urine

My teen has been wearing a brand called Depends. It’s supposed to be a light and nonbulky diaper. I don’t understand, please help.

Comment: Is this a recent change? What is the reason he wets the bed?

Comment: Have you seen a doctor about this?

Answer (score 3):

Bed Wetting for teens is not uncommon. Other than diapers a good option is to monitor water consumption and urination before bed. And a mid-night alarm to get up and urinate would help getting rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure diaper is a good idea. It can  hurt his self esteem, making him feel helpless.

Unless this is some known medical condition and doctor advised to use a diaper, I'd have him just sleep normally, and if he wakes up wet during the night, help him change sheets, and get back to sleep on clean sheets again.

This way he should feel both more comfortable, and more in control over his actions.

If you prefer a diaper anyway (e.g. what I said before, medical condition) then I'd suggest a different brand that can be more comfortable on the skin, and absorb the urine better. From quick search I've made, a brand that got good reviews is [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BRB15MM): (note: link might be blocked by adblockers)

[image: Amazon page with product details]

Surely there are others, you can try few different brands and see which feels best for your teen son. Good luck!

Comment: A teen can change his own sheets.  No need for the parents to be involved.  He can also do the laundry.

Comment: @swbarnes2 ideally, sure. But not all teens are so independent. Sure, it can be part of education, but that's out of scope here. I just know for sure that there are teens who don't change their own sheets and don't do laundry.

Comment: @swbarnes2 It's possible that this particular teen is low functioning. OP didn't give enough information for us to tell if said teen would be able to change his own sheets.

Answer (score 1):

I grew up wearing diapers to bed. Positive family attitude made all the difference. 4 boys and I was the only bedwetter. I also struggled during the day and had way too many daytime accidental wetting issues. I usually wore layers of briefs with plastic pants during the day. I rarely had any teasing from brothers. I decided I would stop the diapers when I entered high school. After a couple months of nightly floods I put myself back in diapers. Later urodynamic testing showed I had a neurogenic bladder and from my history the dr. Said likely since birth. I was also told it was not a curable condition. I guess the trick is attitude.

Answer (score -1):

I have just noticed the question mention usage of *Depends*, so I have possible explanation to the "weird feeling" for the person in question.

*Depends* isn't really a diaper but rather an absorbent, disposable underwear. This means it can absorb only limited amount of urine, and if there is more, it becomes heavy and even start to leak. This can explain the issue.

Solution is simply to use "real" diaper, that can absorb more urine without becoming "heavy" or leaking. (See [my other answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/41516/2513) to get an example of such diaper.)